# Powershell output using export-csv produces different result when script is ran from Powershell Core and Powershell 5.1

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-5.0, windows-scripting, powershell-core

I have a script to retrieve the size of systems hard drive. In this test, the hard drive is a 500 gb drive.
When I run the following script from Visual Code and from Powershell ISE I get two very different results for the hard drive size in the CSV it produces.
The script goes as follows:

```
$file = "c:\temp\hdInfo.csv"
$hdInfo = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_DiskDrive | Select-Object Caption).caption
$hdSize = (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk | Measure-Object -Property Size -Sum).sum /1gb
$psVer = (get-host).Version

$newRow = New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
  'PS_version'      =$psVer
  'HD_Info'         = $hdInfo
  'HD_Size_Received'= $hdSize
  }


$newRow | Export-Csv -Path $file -NoTypeInformation -Append -Force
```

The 1st row of data under the header row is using Visual Code which is using Power Core 6 and the 2nd row of data under the header row is using Powershell 5.1. Two differnt hard drive sizes!?
[Link to picture of csv output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZWnJ.png)

Can someone please help me understand why this is?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your issue. Please create a [MCVE] by excluding/removing things as your object creation, Csv export,  memory conversion (`/1gb`) and summing drives (**are the same drives available in both sessions?**). In other words; what happens if you just do: `Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_LogicalDisk` in both versions/sessions? (do you see the same number of drives, with the same size? which drive differs?).

Comment: Get-Host is not the best way to get PS version info, use `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` instead.

Also, why not use VSCode for both to eliminate a variable? You can easily switch between Windows PowerShell and PowerShell Core inside VSCode.